# Django testing, no 404 response when expected

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I am writing some tests in Django to check the apps which I have written. I am more or less working through what is suggested on here (http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/).
However, when I put something like

```
    resp = self.client.get('made_up_url')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 404)
```

which doesn't exist (and hence I'm hoping for a 404 response, i.e. the test will pass)...but the test fails saying 200!=400, i.e. it seems to think that the made_up_url is a valid page.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the `print resp` shows?

Comment: Did you try `/made_up_url`?

Comment: That's strange. So if I go to made_up_url, I get the 404 page I have written. While if I log what 'resp' is, I get the html for my 404 page. I have played around with Debug (True/False) in my settings page a little, and I have a "TESTING" variable which defines which model is produced by my app/models.py depending on whether I am testing or not.....perhaps that is causing the issue

Comment: Maybe I should add the following. In my main app.models, I have:
        if TESTING:
            blah(models.Model)
        else:
            blah2(models.Model)
When I have DEBUG = False, and my TESTING as false, I get my 404 page fine....the model defined within TESTING=False, has a fully populated database....The model within TESTING=True, has an empty database, which I populate a bit as part of the test process...it's when I have TESTING=True, that I just can't get a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `self.client.get` an unexistent URL: `made_up_url`. As dan-klasson told you, you need to get `/made_up_url`.

I suggest that, instead of hardcoding the URL in the `self.client.get` arguments, first [name the related URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in your `urls.py` file. So you can resolve it via the `reverse` function.

Then, once you have a `name` for it, you can do this in your unit tests:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('made_up_url')
resp = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 404)
```

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean exactly? Just adding an extra url to my urlpatterns? Like url(r'^made_up_url/$', view, name='made_up_url')? What would my view say...or can I just use a view which already exists?

Comment: I ask because, if I logged the HTML response when I self.client.get a non-existent url, I would get the HTML for my 404 view...which is strange as obviously some part of Django figured it was a 404 error but my test decided this 404 page constituted a 200 response

Comment: Yep, I think I got your method to "work" in the sense, that the same thing happens as before...i.e. if I see what resp look like, it's my 404 page HTML but the resp.status_code is still 200 :(

Comment: So I've just deleted my handler404 and it all works fine....Strange. Is there something in settings I should have changed for my own 404 to function properly?

Comment: But my 404 page still loads in the browser :S!! Even though I have deleted my handler404. Bizarre

Comment: Ok, sorry for the repeated comments. I think my original way works. I think deleting my handler404 solved it? Maybe I was missing a '/'...who knows...it's working now anyway.